# Why square the time unit from average rate of change: $\frac{units}{time^2}$

Tags: calculus

Given:
f(t) = the RATE at which widgets are produced (per hour)

Incidentally, $\int_a^b f(t)dt$ is the TOTAL amount of widgets produced during [a,b]

Now, If you want to know the average rate of change during [a,b], 
you'd calculate  $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
Why are the units supposed to be $$N\frac{widgets}{hour^2}$$

Comment: What is $N$? According to your formula of the average rate, it is obvious the unit should be $$\frac{\text{widgets}}{\text{hour}^2},$$ because the unit of $f(t)$ is $\dfrac{\text{widgets}}{\text{hour}}$, and the unit of $a$ and $b$ are $\text{hour}$.

Comment: "Obvious" b/c integral is the product of those to units?  (Area)

Answer (score 0):

I think your average rate of change during $[a,b]$ is wrong.

What you are calculating is the average rate of change of the rate of change, i.e. the acceleration of the widgets produced. What you should calculate is the total amount of widgets produced divided by change in time.

Therefore, the correct formula for average rate of change should be: $\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}$ where $F(x)$ is the original function of $f(x)$ ($F'(x)=f(x)$).

Thus, the unit should still be widgets/hour which is the same as that of the rate at which widgets are produced.